# Migrating from editorAction to org.eclipse.ui.menus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

For a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009796/override-marker-click-action) which I had, I found a solution which makes use of some deprecated API's.

So to run something when the user click on a marker, I added this into my `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editorActions">
    <editorContribution targetID="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.CEditor"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ruler.actions">
         <action
               actionID="RulerClick"
               class="com.example.MarkerClickAction"
               id="com.example.MarkerClickAction"
               label="%Dummy.label">
         </action>
    </editorContribution>
</extension>
```

I tried to translate the `editorActions` to `org.eclipse.ui.menus` and so far I came up with this:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         allPopups="false"
         locationURI="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.CEditor">
      <command
            commandId="com.example.MarkerClickAction"
            description="Opens Quick Fix when the user clicks a marker"
            id="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ruler.actions"
            name="Marker Click Action">
      </command>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
        class="com.example.MarkerClickAction"
        commandId="com.example.MarkerAction">
    </handler>
</extension>
```

The single thing which I don't know how to map is the `actionID="RulerClick"` field from the `<action>`.
Where should I configure that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need a `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point to define the command id.

There isn't a simple mapping from a handler to an old action.

The handler will usually extends `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler`.

The `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil` class provides a number of helper methods for handlers to do things like getting the active editor.

Note that although `org.eclipse.ui.editorActions` is marked as deprecated it is very unlikely that it will ever be removed as too much existing code uses it.

Comment: Thanks for the `commands` tip, missed that. I don't have a problem to get the active editor. The problem is that I want the handler to execute only when a `RulerClick` action occured

Comment: Would you suggest to don't overwork and stick instead with the `editorAction` 
 solution?

Comment: If the current code is working OK I don't see any point it changing it.

Comment: I was just thinking to use the "latest technologies" and don't introduce deprecated code